# How Can I fetch/scrape HTML text and images to Windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

Hello, 

I want to know that, How can I scrape a HTML Site's text which are in a list (ul, li) in Windows phone. I want to make a rss feed reader. Please in details, I am new in HTMLAgilityPack.


thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as simple as you would think. You will have to use HTMLAgility pack to parse and normalize the HTML content. but then you will need to go through each node to assess if it's content node or not, i.e. you would want to ignore DIVs, Embeds etc.

I'll try to help you get started.

READ THE DOCUMENT

```
Uri url = new Uri(<Your url>);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url.AbsoluteUri);
```

HERE IS HOW YOU CAN EXTRACT THE IMAGE AND Text tags

```
var docNode = documentNode;
// if you just want all text withing the document then life is simpler.
string htmlText = docNode.InnerText;

// Get images
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> imageNodes = docNode.Descendants("img");
// Now iterate through all the images and do what you like...
```

If you want to implement a Readability/Instapaper like cleanup then download NReadability from https://github.com/marek-stoj/NReadability